# How to count frequency of columns in row in a typedpipe in scalding?

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce, scalding

I'm currently working on a mapreduce job using scalding. I'm trying to threshold based on how many times I see a particular value among the rows in my typedpipe. For example, if I had these rows in my typedpipe:

### Column 1 | Column 2

### 'hi'     | 'hey'

### 'hi'     | 'ho'

### 'hi'    | 'ho'

### 'bye'    | 'bye'

I would want to append to each row the frequency I saw the value in column 1 and column 2 in every row. Meaning the output would look like:

### Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 1 Freq | Column 2 Freq

### 'hi'     | 'hey'| 3 | 1

### 'hi'     | 'ho' | 3 | 2

### 'hi'    | 'ho' | 3 | 2

### 'bye'    | 'bye' | 1 | 1

Currently, I'm doing that by grouping the typed pipe by each column, like so:

```
  val key2Freqs = input.groupBy('key2) {
    _.size('key2Freq)
  }.rename('key2 -> 'key2Right).project('key2Right, 'key2Freq);
```

Then joining the original input with key2Freqs like so:

```
  .joinWithSmaller('key2 -> 'key2Right, key2Freqs, joiner = new LeftJoin)
```

However, this is really slow and seems to me to be pretty inefficient for what is essentially a pretty simple task. It gets especially long b/c I have 6 different keys that I want to get these values for, and I am currently mapping and joining 6 different times in my job. There must be a better way to do this, right?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of the different values in each column is small enough to fit them all into memory, you could `.map` your columns into `Map[String,Int]`, and then `.groupAll.sum` to count them all in one go (I am using the "typed api" notation, don't quite remember how exactly this is done in the fields api, but you get the idea). You'll need to use the `MapMonoid` from [algebird](https://github.com/twitter/algebird/blob/develop/algebird-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/algebird/MapAlgebra.scala#L95), or just write your own if you don't want to add a dependency for this one thing, it is not hard. 
You'd then end up with a pipe, containing a single entry for the resulting `Map`. Now, you can get your original pipe, and do `.crossWithTiny` to bring the map with counts into it, and then `.map` to extract individual counts.

Otherwise, if you can't keep all that in memory, then what are you doing now seems like it is the only way ... unless you are actually looking for an approximation of "top hitters", rather than exact counts of the entire universe ... in which case, check out algebird's [SketchMap](https://gist.github.com/bigsnarfdude/ea883a19232833cf2647).